# How can I specify a shared object version in javacpp link?

Tags: java, javacpp

I have a library file like `libfoo.so.1.55.0` and would like to include it in the generated platform jar using [javacpp-presset](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets). What is the correct way to add the library to the `link` or `linkResources` fields in the `@Platform` annotation?

I've tried `foo`, `foo@.1.55.0` which doesn't work. Notably, removing the version from the shared object file altogether (`libfoo.so`) does indeed work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version we need to specify here isn't related to the filename, but the SONAME. Check its value with `readelf -d`.